# simulator for windows phone 7 and webos

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, simulator, webos

Can anybody provide the links to simulators for windows phone 7 and WebOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Windows Phone 7 Development Tools from the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com), which includes the Windows Phone 7 emulator (and everything else you need to develop applications for WP7).

The [Palm SDK](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=page&id=1788&Itemid=321) includes the WebOS emulator. There is a useful article on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22681/test-drive-webos-without-buying-a-phone/) that explains how to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

To get the webOS Emulator, go to http://developer.palm.com/ and sign up for the developer program.   To join the "Early Access" program, after you have your regular developer account set up, see https://developer.palm.com/content/resources/develop/webos_3_0_developer_beta.html